# Android NDK java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have a working project that uses NDK.

I'm trying to import the NDK libraries into another project, and calling the NDK functions from this new project.

I've copied the jni, libs and obj folders(including sub-folders) from the working project to the new project.

I've then tried to call the functions in the new project. However, I'm getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError whenever I call the function.

Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects packet name and activity name same?